# SELECT COUNT(*) SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have this:

```
SELECT AssignmentID
FROM ProblemView
GROUP BY AssignmentID
```

which returns 32 rows.
But really what I want is the number 32.
If I do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM lru.ProblemView
GROUP BY AssignmentID
```

I still get 32 rows, and the column is merely the count of the number of Assignments per problem.

I just need the number 32.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
SELECT count(distinct AssignmentID) 
FROM ProblemView
```

Comment: Sheesh.  When am I ever going to learn SQL Server?  Thank you very much!